# Fleshed out .po file sample

Tags: internationalization, gettext, po

I almost feel stupid asking this, but... are there any good sample .po files out there? I have been reading the GNU gettext manual and while it specifies the general structure it doesn't go into as much detail as I would like. Plus I would really like an actual fleshed out .po file that utilizes its more advanced functions (like `msgctxt`, `#| msgctxt` etc) so that I can run tests against it.

Any tips on where to find something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for some big open-source project, like openSUSE (Linux distro) - po files are available on http://svn.opensuse.org/svn/opensuse-i18n/trunk/, I'm sure you'll find there every possible  function used.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple one

```
# My comment
#. Programmer comment
#: location.c:23
#| msgctxt "Old context"
#| msgid "Won"
#, fuzzy
msgctxt "Disambiguation for context"
msgid "One"
msgstr "Een"
```

I think that covers everything.  There are other things like obsolete units, c-format markers.  I think I've placed previous messages #| in the correct place and you might want to check the format.